# Searching for missing State Combinator for Lens

Tags: haskell, state-monad, lenses, haskell-lens

I currently have code that looks like this:

```
do
  x <- use foo
  foo <~ runFoo x
```

where `foo` is a `Lens` to a `Foo` field and `runFoo :: MonadState m => Foo -> m Foo`

I think there should be a way to do this operation in one line, but I cannot find it.  I think it ought to have a comment like:

```
(????) :: MonadState s m => Lens' s a -> (a -> m a) -> m a
```

**Questions:**

- Does such a combinator exist? if so what is it?
- When I run into another question like this, what is the best way to search for it (i.e. Usually I would just type this into Hoogle but I've not had good luck doing that with the lens library)
- Is this actually a primitive combinator found in Control.Monad? (I will be slightly embarrassed if this is yet another job for the kleisli arrow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*lens* doesn't offer such a combinator in a ready-made form. If instead of `runFoo` you had some `g :: a -> a` function, you would be able to use [`(%=)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.0.1/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:-37--61-), which is to `over` what `use` is to `view`, and write simply `foo %= g`. Your desired functionality, though, involves interleaving the `m` effects introduced by `runFoo` in between the getting and setting, which precludes a solution this straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The type signature of the function you are looking for is suspiciously close to that of `>>=`, but with the first argument different.

In particular, it appears as if `use foo :: Monad m => m Foo` and `foo <~ runFoo :: Foo -> m Foo`, so you could use bind directly as `use foo >>= (\x -> foo <~ runFoo x)`.  There's probably an easier/shorter way, but I don't have the full code to play around with.  I'd say just stick with using two lines, and if it's a common enough operation, then define your own combinator for it.

Comment: Have you actually done anything more there then just desugar Haskell's `do` notation? This technique can be used to combined any two lines in a `do` statement.  I want to merge `use` and `(<~)`.